# Why pkg-config overrides 'prefix' with another default one?

Tags: x264, msys2, pkg-config

I have an issue in using pkg-config to link some libraries to a program. The problem is 'prefix' variable in each library pkg-config files (*.pc) are overridden with an unwanted directory leading to building the program could not find the library's header and lib files.

Here, one of '*.pc' files, x264.pc:

```
prefix=/e/x264/x64-windows-rel  
exec_prefix=${prefix}   
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib   
includedir=${prefix}/include    
...
```

I run this from MSYS2 terminal:

```
pkg-config --cflags --debug x264
```

This is some of the output it traced out:

```
...
 Parsing package file 'D:/msys64/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig\x264.pc'
 line>prefix=/e/x264/x64-windows-rel
 Variable declaration, 'prefix' overridden with 'D:/msys64/usr/local'
...
```

Note that MSYS2 and pkg-config are updated to newest versions.

Could anybody tell me why it happens and how to solve the issue without renaming 'prefix' to something else.?
Thanks.

Comment: Why have you configured libx264 with this path? default for x264.pc is prefix=/usr/local. Or are you asking why this override with 'D:/msys64/usr/local'?

Comment: Have you PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR enviroment variable set?

Comment: @nobody555 Sine it's legal to set any valid path in the pkg file, I want to pkg-config find the my path instead of any default one. I set PKG_CONFIG_PATH but not PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your pkg-config was compiled with `--enable-define-prefix` option (look like default for Windows targets) and your .pc file is located in directory with `pkgconfig` name (`D:/msys64/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig\x264.pc`). Btw why is .pc file installed in `D:/msys64/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` while libraries are installed elsewhere?

Here is quote from pkg-config manual page:

```
    --define-prefix
          --dont-define-prefix  These  options  control whether pkg-config
          overrides the value of the variable prefix  in  each  .pc  file.
          With  --define-prefix, pkg-config uses the installed location of
          the .pc file to determine the prefix. --dont-define-prefix  pre-
          vents this behavior. The default is usually --define-prefix.

          When this feature is enabled and a .pc file is found in a direc-
          tory named pkgconfig, the prefix for that package is assumed  to
          be  the  grandparent  of the directory where the file was found,
          and the prefix variable is overridden for that file accordingly.

          If  the value of a variable in a .pc file begins with the origi-
          nal, non-overridden, value of  the  prefix  variable,  then  the
          overridden value of prefix is used instead. This allows the fea-
          ture to work even when the variables have been expanded  in  the
          .pc file.
```

So you can disable this behavior by `--dont-define-prefix` option.

[pkg-config manual page (source code)](https://github.com/freedesktop/pkg-config/blob/master/pkg-config.1)

[pkg-config manual page (rendered)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pkg-config/)

P.S. MSYS2 have few pkg-config packages. And you supposed to use `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config` or `mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config`. Do NOT use `msys/pkg-config`.

Comment: You're right when point out the cause. 
For your question, I put the library elsewhere instead of one relative to "usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" because the library is used by other programs.

Addition, I found two instances of pkg-config.exe exist in subfolders of MSYS2 both have version 0.29.2 but each behaves differently in its own way:

msys64/mingw64/bin/pkg-config.exe 
 overrides 'prefix' by default.

msys64/usr/bin/pkg-config.exe 
 does not overrides 'prefix' by default.